# tkinter exe added to startup shows console window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file, tkinter

I made a python application in python.

**Swaminarayan.py**

```py
import tkinter as Tkinter
def main():
    top = Tkinter.Tk()
    top.geometry("500x500")
    B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Ghanshyam Maharaj")
    B.pack()
    top.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I converted this code to ***.exe*** using [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in virtual environment

**setup.py**

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": []}
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = "Swaminarayan",
    url='https://github.com/ajinzrathod/Swaminarayan',
    version = "0.1",
    description = "My GUI application!",
    options = {
        "build_exe": build_exe_options,
        "bdist_msi": {
            'install_icon': r"F:\executable-python-windows\Swaminarayan\icon.ico", 
            }
        },
    executables = [
        Executable("Swaminarayan.py",
             base=base,
             icon=r"path\to\icon.ico",
             shortcutName='Swaminarayan',
             shortcutDir='DesktopFolder',
             )
        ]
    )
```

and then created MS Installer

```
py setup.py bdist_msi
```

This creates an installer and when I installed `Swaminarayan.exe`, it opens normally without a console window.

I wanted my **Swaminarayan Application** to start at boot.
So I created a batch file in `C:\Users\Ajinkya Rathod\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` named **open.bat**

And pasted the following code

```
"C:\Users\Ajinkya Rathod\AppData\Local\Programs\Swaminarayan\Swaminarayan.exe"
```

Which is the path to my installed **Swaminarayan.exe**

It works perfectly till here.

The main problem is here. When I double-click on the batch file, it also loads a console window. I just want the GUI created with Tkinter. But it also loads the console window.

I can't find the source but some StackOverflow answers asked to used `start` in a batch script like this

```
start "C:\Users\Ajinkya Rathod\AppData\Local\Programs\Swaminarayan\Swaminarayan.exe"
```

But the problem is that including `start` in batch scripts removes the console window along with the GUI application. I don't want my GUI to vanish. I just want to get rid of Console Window.

Trying this since long time. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: @Gerhard The black screened **cmd** window : https://ibb.co/Dbt3V76

Comment: Nope, it is just one liner

Comment: Wait, I will record the screen and send the link.

Comment: Just run the exe directly — forget about bat files.

Comment: But I want my application to run from startup. I want to load it in start-up. 
https://vimeo.com/549822172

Comment: Worked as a charm. You should include this in answer. So that I can upvote you and thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you need to launch your executable from a batch file to run it from the startup folder? You could put the exe in the startup folder or a shortcut to it.

Comment: @Squashman I will surely consider this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's documentaiton, `start`'s `"title"` is optional, but depending on the options used, it can become an issue, like you are experiencing here. Currently your script is starting `cmd` with a title of the script path.

So include the empty title `""`

```
start "" "%localappdata%\Programs\Swaminarayan\Swaminarayan.exe"
```